# WP_Query condition affects posts_per_page count

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to create a new `WP_Query` that displays the last 5 posts from cat 1 that doesn't have a thumbnail. This actually works:

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=5' );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post(); if ( ! has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php } endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

But let's say of the last 5 posts, 3 have the thumbnail; in this case, only 2 posts are displayed. I'd like to have 5 as fixed number of `posts_per_page` and if in the loop end up posts with thumbnail the older posts are displayed (to reach the number of 5), instead of displaying just the 2 without thumbnails.

I tried putting the `if` before `$the_query` but it didn't work.

Comment: how many posts do you have in your category? Do you have more than two that don't have a featured image?

Comment: yep. the problem of my code is that the function gets the last 5 posts and then the filter of the thumbnail is applied. So if 3 posts of these 5 have the thumbnail only 5-3=2 are displayed. The filter should be applied before I think, so the 5 posts selected by posts_per_page are already the ones without the thumbnail.

Comment: try using next_post(); So you could try. if !has_post_thumbnail() do content else $the_query->next_post();  I don't know if that would work. I have never used it

Comment: Where? And it seems deprecated..

Comment: Maybe they changed it to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Comment: I don't get how that function could help..

Comment: ok, never mind that. Thought it might be worth a try. I found an article on here that might help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100585/skip-posts-without-a-thumbnail-in-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to fetch posts, that don't have a featured image, with:

```
$ppp = 5; // posts per page

/**
 * Fetch $ppp posts, without thumbnails, in a given category:
 */
$args = array(
    'cat'            => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

But what if there are not enough posts, without a featured image, in that category? Well, then we can just fill the rest with posts with a featured image:

```
/**
 * Fetch $ppp-x posts in a given category, with thumbnails, if x > 0:
 */
if( $count = count( $posts ) < $ppp ) 
{  
    $args = array(
        'cat'            => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp - $count,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_thumbnail_id',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $myposts = array_merge( $posts, get_posts( $args ) );
}
```

Then you can setup your loop with:

```
global $post;
foreach( $myposts as $post ) 
{
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ?><li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li><?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You might also want to make a check if you got enough posts within the corresponding category.

Notice that this is untested, but I hope you can modify this to your needs.

*ps:* If I remember correctly, @kaiser already solved something similar in the general case, with some extra flavors added ;-)

I will add a link if I find it.

**Update:** Found it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130009/how-to-merge-two-queries-together/130015), I think. There are some interesting answers over there.

Comment: Thanks! Obviously this is the way to go. Unfortunately I tried your snippet but the output is blank..

Comment: It's because I have another query_posts in the same page. I digged in WordPress codex but I'm not able to have them working at the same time.. Here's what I tried: http://pastebin.com/q1a9heG7
The first query is displayed. the second is blank..

Comment: Hi @MultiformeIngegno. Blank page means you probably got a PHP syntax error. I just tried the above code and it worked well on my install. I can see in your pastebin that you're using `query_posts()`, please don't use that. It's not recommended. Check for example this note in the Codex: [*This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes...*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice and it worked like a charm now replacing also the other function with get_posts. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. The problem with `query_posts()` is that it's modifying the main query, which can lead to all kinds of problem. The `get_posts()` function is very handy sometimes, since it's just a simple wrapper for the `WP_Query()` function.

Comment: One problem maybe is that get_posts() doesn't support pagination..

Comment: ps: `get_posts()` supports all the parameters of `WP_Query()`, including pagination.